# Recycler view last item taking more space?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-recyclerview, nestedrecyclerview

I Using recycler Grid view with endless scroll.i have facing new issue on recycler view last item.in first time load last list last item take additional space.when scroll top & comeback again same place it auto assign correct space.i add my issue snapshot & also added my xml file.check out & please explain what issue?

My Main xml  file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linear_detail_list_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/SIZE_5"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.own.ecommerce.ui.activities.ProductDetailsListActivity">



        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_list_options"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/SIZE_5"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/SIZE_10"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/SIZE_10"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/SIZE_10"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_border"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_list_view"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_list_view" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_detail_grid_sorting"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_start_product_detail_5"
                android:layout_weight="0.45"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_border"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_product_detail_5"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_sort" />

                <TextView
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:text="@string/action_sorting" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear_detail_grid_filter"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.45"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_product_detail_5"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_filter" />

                <TextView
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.3"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/action_filter" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_grid_product_detail_grid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/SIZE_10"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/SIZE_10"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:scrollbars="none" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My Adapter class xml  :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/linear_grid_product"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_border"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">



<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


            <com.own.ecommerce.view.SquareImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_grid_product"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.7" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_grid_product"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/SIZE_10"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/SIZE_10"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="start|center"
                android:lines="2"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_grid_product_price"
                style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/SIZE_10"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/SIZE_10"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:gravity="start|center"
                android:lines="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="0.1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/SIZE_10"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_grid_buy"
                    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.80"
                    android:background="@color/black"
                    android:text="@string/nav_frag_home_grid_btn_name"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/img_grid_buy"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="0.20"
                    android:background="@color/light_black"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"
                    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_cart" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

My issue images :

**in first time load,**

[image]

**then scroll & come back again same place it's look prefect,**
[image]

how i fix this issue?

Comment: move android:weightSum="1" from parent linear layout to second linear layout

Answer (score 0):

You have bottomMargin in your root LinearLayout.

```
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/SIZE_5"
```

You should set your root LinearLayout's height as "match_parent" and make your recyclerview's weight as "1".

Comment: i changed my code on your suggestion.but i'm facing new one.now that the last item can't get space but it auto align the same height.still the last item same height.what can i do?